# Windows Batch file for checking if a file exists

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I have tried to find an answer to my question on StackOverflow but I can only find partial answers and I can't glue them together. :)

I have tried to put a short easy batch together but I can't seem to get it to work quite as I'd like to.

```
for /f %%i in (hosts.txt) do (

IF not EXIST "\\%%i\c$\installer\install.bat" echo %%i >> c:\e\nofile.txt)
```

I have a hosts.txt filled with IPs, and I know that on about 50% of the computers that file is on that computer. But all the same all of the IPs turn up in my nofile.txt. What am I missing?

Comment: This works here. Check yout network ressources, permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with rights and access, you could try and run the batch file as a different user. See this post on superuser.com for more information:https://superuser.com/questions/105913/run-as-for-a-bat-file

Comment: I have seen that suggestion, but tha means you have to have the same user on both computers. If I try to use "runas: user2" and on the server only user 1 exists it wont work, will it?

Comment: You could try it. I recently went to a LAN-party, there we all leach from a friend's server using a local account from his server. I don't have this user on my machine, but still I can access his machine with it. In the worst case u can always add this user to your server, but I do not think that to be necessary.